# How to change Nginx firewall status to “active”

Tags: 16.04, command-line, nginx

When I query the netfilter firewall status I get “inactive”:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I want to change it so I can see this:

```
Output
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I have been looking but didn't find any info about how to set the status.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run

```
sudo ufw enable
```

to enable the firewall.

You can get further help on `ufw` on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html) and `man ufw`.

#### Example

```
$ sudo ufw enable
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```